# How do I query links shared by Facebook Pages?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-fql

I can get a user's page/likes list using the graph [/me/likes](https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes).  But how can I return a list of links shared by these Pages?

For example, let's say a user likes the [Facebook Platform Page](http://www.facebook.com/platform).  I can pull this id (`19292868552`) using the [/me/likes](https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes) graph api.  But how can I pull the links that the Facebook Platform Page has shared on their page?

For a regular user you would do something like this:

Sample FQL:

```
SELECT link_id, title, summary, url FROM link WHERE owner IN (19292868552);
```

But for Facebook Pages (like the above Facebook Platform Page example), this returns null.  But the actual [Facebook Platform Page](http://www.facebook.com/platform) shows dozens of links (at least).  How can I get the links shared by these pages?

You can test it here:
[FQL Query Test Console](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/)

Comment: are you wanting to read, for example, the pages wall? Is that what you mean by "links shared by these pages". Please can you clarify your question.

Comment: I tried to clarify above.  But yes, if you visit the Facebook Platform page (http://www.facebook.com/platform) and look at all the links shared on this page.  How can I pull them all via the api? (the same way I can do for a user using the fql query above)

Comment: unless all the posts are public posts, you'll have to be granted permissions or use a valid access_token to read from a page's news feed...

Comment: Yes, I've looked at the permissions available at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/ and don't see anything that allows links that pages share.  Is this right?  I already have a valid access token for our users.  And on my test account I've even granted every single one of the available permissions.  Does this mean that Facebook does not allow this query?  That's odd because these pages are public and don't even require "liking" them to view their links in a browser.

Comment: Got it.  Different format:  https://graph.facebook.com/platform/feed?access_token=HASH  Any clue how to find this via fql?

Comment: using the [graph api explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=40796308305%2Ffeed), calling `https://graph.facebook.com/40796308305/feed` returns me the posts on the wall of the Coca-Cola fan page

Comment: Thanks.  I'm still interested in an FQL solution as this one is far more expensive than I'd like.  With FQL you can select just links, and just links since a certain created_time.  The graph api just dumps all.

Comment: did you ever discover a solution to this? I have a similar problem without much luck... http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9833657/how-to-count-number-of-links-shared-by-a-facebook-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little late to the party here, but I thought I'd post [my gist example](https://gist.github.com/2421193) here. fbconsole makes it fairly simple to extract data through the [Facebook Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) to address this issue.

The caveat is that it was not terribly easy to programmatically extract data through fbconsole so I wrote the `fbconsole.automatically_authenticate` to make it much easier to access this information in a systematic way. This addition has not yet been incorporated into the [master branch of fbconsole](https://github.com/facebook/fbconsole) (it was just posted this morning), but it is available [here](https://github.com/deanmalmgren/fbconsole) in the meantime for those that are interested.